# Overriding a message block in Magento theme affects the admin area

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, global-messages

I wanted to provide a different style and markup for the notices. I thought these were found in a template file `'core/messages'` but it turns out the output comes from a block `Mage_Core_Block_Messages`. When I override this block within my own custom module it works fine. But then in the admin area it also adopts this same markup and style.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find whether request is from admin side or from frontend

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if(Mage::app()-&gt;getStore()-&gt;isAdmin()){
        return true;
    }

    if(Mage::getDesign()-&gt;getArea() == 'adminhtml'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```